# Can charges shield electric force of attraction?

Tags: electrostatics, polarization, coulombs-law, dielectric

[image]

As given in the picture, the scene is magnified billions of times. Now I am ignoring the force of attractions between q2,q6,q3,q7. Will there be force of attractions between q1 and q2? And suppose the number of negative charges tends to infinity? Will the force vanish?

————>*EDIT * *Can we can draw a field line between the negative charges from q1 to q2? And if we place a test charge on it won’t it go of course towards the negative charges? One more thing let’s say we have a dipole. From a novice’s point of view we can confirm that the net charge of whole system is zero. From this logic we can say there would be no field lines emanating from the system. But actually there would be according to your answer. So we do we say that net charge is zero? From what I put it, if there is charge there is field lines

Answer (score 3):

Your question implies that you don't quite understand the type of interaction that is going on between the point charges. Hopefully this will help:

### Coulomb's Law

Coulomb's law states that the force between the point charges is proportional to the product of their charges and inversely proportional to the square of the distance between them.

The formula: `F = k * q1 * q2 / r^2`

You notice that as the distance between the points (`r`) increases, `F` approaches 0. So you could say that the force is basically 0 if `q2` is far enough away from `q1`. But really, even if the force is extremely close to 0, both charges will still be exerting some miniscule force on each other.

The important thing to note here is that
*this law remains true even if there are other point charges in the physical system you are examining.*

### Electrostatic Field

The electrostatic field is affected by each point charge just like the often-used model of spacetime that is "bent" by mass. As layed out in [this](https://lambdageeks.com/electrostatic-force-and-field/) article,

> "To exert the gravity force, there must be a field surrounding the earth, and it’s all other masses so that when another mass attains that field, both masses experience gravity force. Similarly, the electrostatic force, a non-contact force, exerts between two charges when they are in the electrostatic field."

### The Answer

So what you seem to think is that the one charge `q1` "runs out of" force because it is interacting with the other charges. Or those charges "cancel out" `q1`'s force. However, that is a fundamentally flawed way of thinking about it. The point charges are affecting the electrostatic field, and thus every charge is exerting force on every other charge, no matter how many charges there are. The force may be so miniscule that you can treat it as non-existent, but it will still be there.

The lines in the chart that you drew are simply representing the "bending" in the electrostatic field. You could draw any number of lines and it would still be correctly representative of what's really happening. Just because you ran out of lines to draw doesn't mean that the point charge can no longer exert force on any other charge.

I hope this was helpful!

Comment: so we can draw a field line between the negative charges from q1 to q2? And if we place a test charge on it won’t it go of course towards the negative charges?

Comment: One more thing let’s say we have a dipole. From a novice’s point of view we can confirm that the net charge of whole system is zero. From this logic we can say there would be no field lines emanating from the system. But actually there would be according to your answer. So we do we say that net charge is zero? From what I put it, if there is charge there is field lines.

Comment: please respond to this question.

Comment: You cannot analyze a system of charges by only looking at the total (net) charge.  You must also consider the spatial distribution of the charges. In this case, the total (net) charge may be zero, but that does not mean that there is no electric field - indeed, there is! See for instance https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_dipole_moment for a canonical example where this also happens. In particular, note that the total charge of a dipole is zero, but still it produces an electric field!

Comment: @Jakob KS then why do we introduce a concept of net charge if this doesn’t hold valid. I may say then that a charge less object may attract in an electric field?

Comment: Net charge may still be a useful concept even though it isn't always enough to solve an electromagnetic problem. 
A charge-less object is not affected by an electric field. However an object consisting of several charged particles may be affected by a field, even if the net charge adds up to zero.